# Getting Proxy Error at time of integrating Mantis Tool with TestRail.

Tags: php, soap, mantis, testrail

In the TestRail tool when I Integration the mantis tool this time error message.

Step:

1. At Integration page of testrail select the Mantis tool via drop down.
2. Now add the following detail

   ; Please configure your Mantis connection below
   [connection]
   address=http://server name/
   user=*****r
   password=9****15
3. After save the detail successfully.
4. Add time add bug I click on Push button this time I got below error message.

Mantis returned an error SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find  in'http://mantis.systematixwebsolutions.com/my_view_page.php/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl'

Or

Plugin “Mantis” returned an error: Proxy Error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a configuration error. The URL reported in the error message has en extra 'my_view_page.php/'.

It should be `http://mantis.systematixwebsolutions.com/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl`.

Comment: I have remove the My view page from link like that:
http://mantis.systematixwebsolutions.com

But Still got same error message.